# Inserting a button into the DOM with an onclick event for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing some Christmas Eve coding and needed some help. I'm trying to create a Chrome extension where I can insert a button into the DOM after highlighting some text. The main core of the logic lies here:

```
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'button';
button.value = 'test';
button.setAttribute('id', 'bookmark-button');
button.setAttribute('style', 'position:fixed; top:' + top_coord + 'px; left: ' + mid_coord + 'px;');
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('test');
  alert('hello');
});
```

I avoided the setAttribute way because I know you can't do inline Javascript in Chrome extension. Also, this code exists in my content script file.

The button appears, but when I click, nothing happens. Has anybody ran into this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

Checked your code, and it works pretty well on my side:

[image]

Maybe you have a z-index problem on the button or some script errors prevent the click handler execution.